# Load page logged in with meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I am using the built-in Accounts functionality with Meteor.js.  When a user is logged in via a cookie, Meteor appears to load the 'logged-out' version of the page first and then automatically log the user in and reload the page to get the the 'logged-in' version.

You can see this behavior in the sample parties app: http://vdawg-parties.meteor.com/
Register, then reload the page.  It will load the page logged out and then after 2-3 seconds will switched to the logged in version.

Is it possible to load the logged-in version on page load?  It is confusing to load a page and then immediately switch to another page.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is built off a "data on the wire" type structure. This means that initially, when your project loads no actual data has been sent between the server and browser. Because of this there is no way to determine whether a user is logged in or not in a meteorish way without waiting for the data to be downloaded.

This is the reason meteor stores login data in `localStorage` when a user is logged in.

**Loading screen**

It's best to have a loading screen while meteor is downloading/syncing the local collections from the server, in a way that you wait for the user's login to be completed:

**client side html**

```
<template name="YourLoggedInSection">
    {{#if isLoaded}}
        ..your logged in section/or place to log in
    {{else}}
        <h1>Loading</h1>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

**Client side js**

```
Template.YourLoggedInSection.isLoaded = function() {
    return Accounts.loginServicesConfigured();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, and will at least avoid confusion, although unfortunately doesn't help me get rid of my long page load times.

Comment: You could use a server closer to you to cut the times down the most